# can't insert data into sqlite3 using python

Tags: python

I can successfully create table in sqlite3 database using Python but I can't insert data to it

```
# coding: utf-8

import sqlite3

text = "Welcome"

def cur_execute(data):
    con = sqlite3.connect('sqlite3.db')
    try:
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(data)
            con.commit()
    except Exception as why: 
        print(why)
    finally:
        if con: con.close()

cur_execute("CREATE TABLE Hello(test TEXT)")
cur_execute("INSERT INTO Hello VALUES(?)", (text))
```

show to me this error : cur_execute() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

thx.

Comment: if you use `with` for the connection. You do not need to call close.

Answer (score 2):

@zoosuck answer works, but it also removed the sql sanitation built in for the library. You can can use the built in sql sanitization by implementing the following:

```
import sqlite3

text = "Welcome"

def cur_execute(data, args=()):
    con = sqlite3.connect('sqlite3.db')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(data, args)
        con.commit()

cur_execute("CREATE TABLE Hello(test TEXT)")
cur_execute("INSERT INTO Hello VALUES(?)", (text, ))
```

Please note that with the `with` statement, you do not need to close the connection. I removed the try catch around the connection to show the full error if errors do occur.

Additionally, there was a problem with your original code. The second argument in `cur_execute("INSERT INTO Hello VALUES(?)", (text))` needs to be a tuple/list.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this

```
# coding: utf-8

import sqlite3

text = "Welcome"

def cur_execute(data, *args):
    con = sqlite3.connect('sqlite3.db')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(data, args)
        con.commit()

cur_execute("CREATE TABLE Hello(test TEXT)")
cur_execute("INSERT INTO Hello VALUES(?)", text)
```

This way you keep the functionality of cur.execute to escape your input data. This can prevent SQL injection attacks.

If you want to add 2 things into your table you could call your function like this instead.

```
cur_execute("CREATE TABLE Hello2(test1 TEXT, test2 TEXT)")
cur_execute("INSERT INTO Hello2 VALUES(?, ?)", text, "stuff")
```

It will make another table with 2 text fields. Is that what you were asking to do?

Comment: Upvote for not breaking SQL injection attack protection

Comment: @Andrew Guy beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1):

You have defined your `cur_execute` function as only taking one argument, and then trying to pass two arguments to it, as zoosuck has said.

However, his method is still vulnerable to sql injection - you should let the database API handle string formatting.  You want to be able to pass two arguments to your function, not just the one. You could try:

```
import sqlite3

data = "Welcome"

def cur_execute(data,*args):
    con = sqlite3.connect('sqlite3.db')
    try:
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            if args is not None:
                cur.execute(data,args)
            else:
                cur.execute(data)
            con.commit()
    except Exception as why: 
        print(why)
    finally:
        if con: con.close()

cur_execute("CREATE TABLE Hello(test TEXT)")
cur_execute("INSERT INTO Hello VALUES(?)", (data))
```

Comment: thx, can I add two thing to insert like

data1 = "welcome1"

data2 = "welcome2"

how can I insert it to table

thx

Answer (score 0):

The function take one parameter: SQL(string type), your second call give it two parameters, just change your code to format the SQL will be ok:

```
import sqlite3

data = "Welcome"

def cur_execute(data):
    con = sqlite3.connect('sqlite3.db')
    try:
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute(data)
            con.commit()
    except Exception as why: 
        print(why)
    finally:
        if con: con.close()

cur_execute("CREATE TABLE Hello(test TEXT)")
cur_execute("INSERT INTO Hello VALUES('{0}')".format(data)) # format sql and call it
```

Comment: Hi;

what if I wan't to insert two data

data1 = "welcome"
data2 = "welcome2"
cur_execute("CREATE TABLE Hello(test TEXT, test2 TEXT)")

how can I insert data1 & data2

Comment: You need to call the function twice.